# JavaScript validator with 2 submit buttons

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm using a JavaScript validator from http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml. The problem I'm facing is that I have one button that saves the registration (here I need to check for `name` and `last name`) and the second button which checks the entire form. However, if I press any button, it checks the entire form.

```
<form id="ministerial" name="register" action="" method="post">
  <label>Title: </label>
  <input type="text" name="title" value="" />
  <label>First Name: </label>
  <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" />
  <label>Last Name: </label>
  <input type="text" name="last_name" value="" />
  <label>Organization: </label>
  <input type="text" name="organization" value="" />
...
  <input type="submit" name="save" value="SAVE REGISTRATION" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT REGISTRATION" />
</form>
<script  type="text/javascript">
 var frmvalidator = new Validator("ministerial");
 frmvalidator.addValidation("title","req","Please enter a title");
 frmvalidator.addValidation("first_name","req","Please enter the first name");
 frmvalidator.addValidation("last_name","req","Please enter the last name");
 frmvalidator.addValidation("organization","req","Please enter the organization");
</script>
```

Comment: i'v added a simplified code of the form. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work. Add validation for proper input fields onClick:

```
<form id="ministerial" name="register" action="" method="post">
      <label>Title: </label>
      <input type="text" name="title" value="" />
      <label>First Name: </label>
      <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" />
      <label>Last Name: </label>
      <input type="text" name="last_name" value="" />
      <label>Organization: </label>
      <input type="text" name="organization" value="" />
    ...
      <input type="submit" name="save" value="SAVE REGISTRATION" onclick="return btnSave_click();" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT REGISTRATION" onclick="return btnRegister_click();" />
    </form>
    <script  type="text/javascript">
     var frmvalidator = new Validator("ministerial");

     function btnSave_click(){
        frmvalidator.clearAllValidations();
        frmvalidator.addValidation("first_name","req","Please enter the first name");
        frmvalidator.addValidation("last_name","req","Please enter the last name");
        return true;
     }
     function btnRegister_click(){
        frmvalidator.clearAllValidations();
        frmvalidator.addValidation("title","req","Please enter a title");
        frmvalidator.addValidation("organization","req","Please enter the organization");
        return true;
     }
    </script>
```

Comment: i added the onClick and it doesn't check for anything and the form isn't submitting anymore. i think the validator overrides it.

Comment: ops. forgot to add () in onclick attribute. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will need to write a custom validation function

Comment: the javascript validator offers custom validation but i couldn't see any custom validation for more than one submit button

Comment: That's why you will need to write it yourself